# Prevent callback return type from including additional properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an interface `Foo` and a function `bar` that takes in a callback that returns a `Foo`.

```ts
interface Foo {
    foo: string;
}

function bar(callback: () => Foo): Foo {
    return callback();
}
```

When I call this, if I add properties to my returned value other than `foo`, the compiler does not throw an error.

```ts
// throws an error as expected
const x: Foo = { foo: 'abc', baz: 'def' };

// does not throw an error
const y = bar(() => ({ foo: 'abc', baz: 'def' }));
```

How can I ensure that the object has no other properties than what are specified in `Foo`?  I've tried using a `type` instead of an `interface` with the same results.  Here's the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrjAK4gJjDojIBGcKAB4AKgD4AFAjgAbGQIQBrUhICUyALxi0mVaQxY8BKBDCsovaXIWK19JrgD0j5GAAWUdAHcyyOL2hPKD9fCAAPAAcITggAE1wEHgpkMP1MTRxCEmQAIjg+BByAGn44AC9SHNiIGBzkBnonF1j0CF8QdDBXD28-AKgghKSugE8MgSgJNU1tCWws9Er8wpKBCtzq2vrVVXogA).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) only happens in specific circumstances, and you've found one where it doesn't.  Types (including interfaces like `Foo`) in TypeScript are open-ended and extendable; you can define an interface like

```
interface Baz extends Foo {
  baz: string;
}
```

and return a `Baz` inside the `bar()` callback, and it's a valid `Foo`:

```
const baz: Baz = { foo: "abc", baz: "def" };
const foo: Foo = baz; // no error
const z = bar(() => baz); // no error...
```

TypeScript doesn't have a concrete type correpsonding to [*exactly*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) `Foo` with no extra properties.  It is possible, however, to use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) which represents "`Foo` with no known extra properties".  Note the "*known*" caveat, there... it will come up later:

```
function bar<
  F extends Foo & { [K in keyof F]: K extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] : never }
>(callback: () => F): Foo {
  return callback();
}
```

Here I've made `bar()` into a generic function which takes a callback of type `() => F`, where `F` is constrained to `Foo`, as well as to a mapped conditional type.  This mapped type takes any known extra keys and changes the property type to be `never`, which is not possible.  For example, if `F` is `Baz`, then the constraint is `Foo & { foo: string, baz: never }`.  Since `Baz` does not extend `{ foo: string, baz: never }`, you'll get an error if you try to call `bar()` on a function known to return a `Baz`:

```
const y = bar(() => ({ foo: "abc", baz: "def" })); // error, generic constraint failed
//  -----------------------------> ~~~
// "string" is not assignable to "never"

const z = bar(() => baz); // error! "string" is not assignable to "never"
// ---------------> ~~~
```

That will at least prevent people from returning object literals with extra properties.

---

However, it is not a perfect solution.  The variable `foo` from before is annotated as type `Foo`, but was initialized with a value of type `Baz`.  The compiler only knows or cares that `foo` is of type `Foo`.  It has completely forgotten that `foo` is also of type `Baz`.  Therefore it does not know that `foo` has a `"baz"` property, and will not prevent this:

```
const oops = bar(() => foo); // still no error... 
// foo has a "baz" property but the compiler forgot
// no way around this in TypeScript, sorry
```

There's nothing to be done there, I'm afraid, other than a runtime check.  If you really want to see exact types in TypeScript you might want to go over to the [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and give it a .  But maybe the above solution is enough for your use case.

Oh well; hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrqJLIigEJwBeyEAD0ggAJmTSYc+ZACNepClRB1GzBOhAVZ85Nz4BeHIRLIARHBkJTAGm09SpkRBinkDeus1hj6UhiyGcjz0uDAAriAIYMAa2lAAPNKo-EIQouL+yABkRgDaANLIoMgA1hAAnugwaAC6pIWCwmKlFVUSWAD87QU1yKQgEABu0G64AHwAFAhwADYzcgglpBMAlMj6Y2grfpJ4BFAQYGFQIMjTcwslq-RMuJ5aAjsBRkS+ZhZWtkEOTi5utMgAPSA-hQKDoKC2QRIMjiAAO4Lh0DA5TOAAsIIsaHcNFpUYE4FAJqt1psJtgfA4PjY7D9nK4GCsVgDgaDwZDkNQ0tBgAgzrjKHBWIQhTMICIcV5kAY4sS1hs7MygSDoOyAISSrSYOHiAlEkkK15K1kgLCqiEAOitPmQaLg4jgZiCrgR6CRUBRsjC3jAGP5AFs4cAxVBjFBqOgwLgTVgAO5wVGE9ARETIX3AcTFAAq5SRAGUEFQ4WBbGQIVByrggA)

Comment: Is it possible to make this imperfect solution into an `Exactish<T>` type?

Comment: It's still a generic constraint, so you can't do `Exactish<T>` but you can do `Exactish<T, X extends T>` and have your function generic in `X`.  Like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671).